# Can we improve speed of build in application consist of more than 15 projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I prepare a project in which there are more than 15 projects and each have ten to twelve user controls. I need to build project in order to run but it takes a lot of time to build the projects. Anyone knows how to increase the speed of a build in visual studio 2010?

Comment: Define: "a lot of time". Minutes? Hours? Days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to use build with multiple processes, just add /MP command to the compiler's command line, it dramatically speeds up the compiling process on multi-core CPUs. However, it works only in release configurations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using project reference across projects. Instead of doing this build project and put the dll in some reference directory, now any project which needs to refer other project will pick the dll from this directory. This way you will be building only one project at a time.

You start with the project which doesn't have any reference, like Model or Utility, then move up with project which has one or two dependency, and hence continue.

Hope this works for you.